# How to write sql to set alter a column's default value in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, alter

I have a table [Product] with a column [CreateTime] datetime null, and is has some data already.

How can I set the column [CreateTime] 's default value to getdate(), and make the new added data to have a  default value getdate() for column  [CreateTime].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change a default - you will need to first drop it, and then recreate it.

In order to drop it, you need to know its name, and then use

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
  DROP CONSTRAINT yourOldDefaultConstraint
```

Once you've done that, you can add a new default constraint, and in order to apply it to existing rows, use the "WITH VALUES" part:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product
   ADD CONSTRAINT NewDefaultConstraintName
   DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreateTime WITH VALUES
```

Oops - sorry, the "WITH VALUES" only seems to work if you create a DEFAULT constraint at the time you create the table, or if you add the column - it doesn't seem to get applied to an existing column.

In this case you would just have to follow your ALTER TABLE statement with something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.T_Product
SET CreateTime = GETDATE()
WHERE CreateTime IS NULL
```

That should do the trick, too!

Marc